# Function from $R^n$ to $R^n$ that makes one of its positive coordinates stand out.

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I am searching for continuous function $f$ that takes a vector in $R^{n}_{+}$ to $R^{n}$. What I need the function to accomplish is:

Given $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in R^n$, for some $\bar{i}$ such that $x_{\bar{i}}>0$, $f_{\bar{i}}(x)>f_{j}(x)$ $\forall j\neq i$.

In words, the function makes one of the positive coordinates "stand out" from the rest, but the coordinate that stands out has to be positive to begin with. It can be any of the coordinates with positive value but not a null coordinate.

If it helps, it can be assumed that the domain of the function is the simplex $\{x\in R^{n}_{+}| \sum_i x_i =1\}$.

A few examples in $R^3$:

$x = (0,2,2)$ $\rightarrow$ $f(x)=(0,2.5,3)$ would be acceptable.
$x = (0,2,2)$ $\rightarrow$ $f(x)=(0,3,2.8)$ would also be acceptable.

What I don't want is make a zero stand out, as in

$x = (0,2,2)$ $\rightarrow$ $f(x)=(3,2.5,2)$ would not be acceptable.

I'm having trouble deciding if such a function exists. Or perhaps, if it does, it must be discontinuous. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does $R^n_+$ mean all coordinates positive? [since you say $f$ "takes a vector in $R_n^+$ to something in $R^n$ it thus depends on what you mean by $R_n^+.$]

Comment: Is the domain of $f$ a vector or a number? The words say "vector": but the explanation says $f(x_i)$. Can you provide a sample? What might $f$ do with input $(1,2)$?

Comment: cofeemath $R^n$ means all coordinates greater or equal to zero.

Comment: Ethan, The domain is a vector space. You are right, I meant $f_i(x)$ Will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no continuous way to break ties.

Consider the two dimensional case on the simplex $x+y=2$ (for convenience), and suppose

$$
f(1,1) = (a,b) \quad a > b .
$$

Then look at 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(1-x, 1+x)
$$

When $x > 0$ is sufficiently small each coordinate of $f(1-x, 1+x)$ must be within $(a-b)/3$ of its limit, but the first must be less than the second. That's a contradiction.

This counterexample extends to all dimensions.

---

Previous partial answer, left here for the record.

If you're willing to settle for $\ge$ then the function that maps a vector to the constant vector whose entries are all equal to the maximum entry will do the job. If not, then you need a continuous way to break ties. I don't see one at the moment.

Note: asking for positivity is redundant since the domain is the simplex - nonnegative entries that sum to $1$.

Edit: I see from your edited question that you don't want ties. I may delete this answer soon.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. I have no way of breaking ties. Thank you for your answer.